# Jquery mobile selectmenu creating flickering effect on scrolling page in ios device

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, select-menu

I am developing a phonegap application and i'm using jquery mobile's selectmenu for dropdown option. When i am changing the selected item on the dropdown on a non scrolling page it's working fine but when i'm doing the same in scrolling page then the page flickers and flashes slightly. I am getting this problem in ios device only, in android its working absolutely fine.

can anyone help me, as i have searched alot on google wasted my whole day but didn't get any solution.

please help me

here is the demo `http://54.200.148.163/lfservice/lib/demo.html`
try this in the Iphone 5 or Iphone 6

Thanks

Comment: Please provide an example (both code and url - jsfiddle or live site)

Comment: sorry but i have never used jsfiddle before.

Comment: Anything that will provide an example is fine, but your code must be supplied in the question or it's likely to be downvoted, closed or simply ignored.

Comment: ok.. let me try with jsfiddle then
Thanks

Comment: http://54.200.148.163/lfservice/lib/demo.html

Here is the demo. and I'm getting fluctuating effect on device when i am selecting a item from the dropdown(default unit).
try this on iphone 5 or 6

Comment: Works on my device (iPhone 4S, iOS7). Which iOS version are you using?

Comment: this is working in browser but not in application

Answer (score 0):

Change your doctype to the HTML5 doctype and get rid of that IE6/7/8 specific CSS in the HEAD